# Can we use header in place of footer and vice versa in html5?

Tags: html

Can we do this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE8FB.jpg)

Comment: You do what you want with your dom and positionnement. It Just more readable and maintainable when header is placed in header and footer in footer ;-)

Comment: yes we can, there is only one limit..... your imaginations.

Comment: why???????????????:D

Comment: NNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOO - it would be bad!!! - just cos you can do something does NOT mean you should do it!

Comment: place doesnt matter, its semantics

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: A page header contains introductory information about the page. There are very few scenarios where you would want the user to read the introduction last.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.
However, it doesn't follow semantic html. But there is absolutely no reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Though semantically wrong, it can be done.   and  are merely block elements.  The whole point of introducing these tags are because people always code write like this and didn't add any semantic context to the HTML:

```
<DIV class="header"></DIV>
```

Replacing this with:

```
<HEADER></HEADER>
```

made more sense.

Point  being: It's about semantics.  So unless it's a huge amount of work just keep the header on top so that web in general makes more sense.

Comment: When you do a -1, be kind enough to justify it as well.